# How to change numbers to random positions in PHP

Tags: php

How would I go about changing the following numbers around to a random positions in php?

Do I need to explode the numbers?

40,52,78,81,25,83,37,77

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$arr = explode(',', '40,52,78,81,25,83,37,77');
shuffle($arr);
echo implode(',', $arr);
```

http://ideone.com/sh2uH

Answer (score 1):

So you want to shuffle the array order?  Use PHP's shuffle function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

EDIT:
Didn't realise your numbers were in a string. The other answer sums it up.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the numbers are in a string:

```
$numbers = '40,52,78,81,25,83,37,77';
$numbers = explode(',',$numbers);
shuffle($numbers);
$numbers = implode(',',$numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
$string = "40,52,78,81,25,83,37,77";
$numbers = explode(",", $string);
shuffle($numbers);
print_r($numbers);
```

`explode` breaks the string out into an array separating entries by `,`

`shuffle` will operate on the array by reference and put them in random order